# Como puedo controlar en que momento se renderice un useEffect en React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, useeffect

Necesito mostrar en una tabla las transacciones realizadas por el usuario que inició sesión en la aplicación pasando id del usuario, que es la clave foranea en la tabla de transacciones, cuando el usuario inicia sesión solo obtengo el nombre de usuario, la contraseña y el token de acceso del usuario. Entonces, la única forma que encontré para obtener la información del usuario que inició sesión {nombre de usuario, id, nombre ...} fue usando el nombre de usuario proporcionado por el usuario cuando inició sesión.

Está funcionando, si me renderiza los datos, pero el componente tiene que hacer como 80 peticiones antes de que los datos se muestren en la tabla y despues de unos fallos del principio se renderiza y la descripcion de los errors dicen que la identificación que estoy pasando es "indefinida". Como se muestra en la siguiente captura de pantalla:
[Console errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsAvN.png)

Codigo de este componente:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table';
import { CdrsContext } from '../contexts/CDRDownloadingContext';
import { UserContext } from '../contexts/UserContext';
import UseAuth from '../hooks/UseAuth';
import styles from './stylePages/CDRDownloading.module.css'

const CDRTable = () => {
    const { getUserDetails, record } = useContext(UserContext)
    const { cdrListFiltered, getCdrsListMadeByUser } = useContext(CdrsContext);
    const { auth } = UseAuth();

    /*************************************
    * GETTING THE USER ID TO GET THE LIST OF REPORT REQUESTS SENT BY THE SPECIFIC USER
    //*************************************/

    // Auth.username is providin an object type user from the backend, which among the properties
    // it contains the user id. 
    const extractedUsername = auth.username;
    console.log(extractedUsername);

    // Once the user details have been loaded with the getUserDetails(extractedUsername); function which expects a username to get data.
    // I get the especific user and with the record 

    const extractedUserId = record.serie;
    console.log(extractedUserById)
    //**************************************/

    /**
     * Function to mount the list of report requests made by the logged in user
     */
    useEffect(() => {
        getUserDetails(extractedUsername);
        getCdrsListMadeByUser(extractedUserId)
    }, [extractedUserId]);

    const typeReport = {
        0: 'Cliente',
        1: 'Proveedor'
    }

    const callFilter = {
        0: 'Contestadas',
        1: 'No contestadas',
        2: 'Todas'
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <br />
            </div>
            <Table className={styles.table}>
                <thead className={styles.tableHead}>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>FECHA CONSULTA</th>
                        {/* <th>ID USUARIO</th> */}
                        <th>EMAIL</th>
                        <th>FECHA INICIAL</th>
                        <th>FECHA FINAL</th>
                        <th>TIPO REPORTE</th>
                        <th>NOMBRE CLIENTE/PROVEEDOR</th>
                        <th>RGIDs</th>
                        <th>ESTADO</th>
                        <th>PROCESO INICIADO</th>
                        <th>PROCESO FINALIZADO</th>
                        <th>FILTRO LLAMADA</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {cdrListFiltered?.map((report, reportIndex) => (
                        <tr key={reportIndex} >
                            <td>{reportIndex + 1}</td>      
                            <td>{report.requestDate}</td>
                            {/* <td>{report.requestUserId}</td> */}
                            <td>{report.requestEmail}</td>
                            <td>{report.startDate}</td>
                            <td>{report.endDate}</td>
                            <td>{typeReport[report.reportType]}</td>
                            <td>{report.contactId}</td>
                            <td>{report.rgids}</td>
                            <td>{report.status}</td>
                            <td>{report.processStart}</td>
                            <td>{report.processFinish}</td>
                            <td>{callFilter[report.callQuery]}</td>
                        </tr>
                        )
                    )}
                </tbody>
            </Table>
        </>
    )
}

export default CDRTable
```

Sabe alguien como puedo hacer para que esto no pase, como puedo hacer que se renderice una vez tenga lista la variable que continue el Id del usuario
para pasarlo como parametro de la funcion, y no que se llame en el primer renderizado?

Comment: No entendī, en qué momento quieres que se renderice? cuando cambie qué variable?

Comment: Quiero que se renderice cuando obtenga la variable `const extractedUserId = record.serie;` ya que es la variable que se pasa como parametro a la funcion `getCdrsListMadeByUser(extractedUserId)` que esta dentro del `useEffect`. Esta funcion consume una **API** que trae las transacciones que ha hecho el usuario logeado `CdrsContext`. Pero como se muestra en el pantallazo **Console errors **, en el primer renderizado no se esta asignando el `id` en la funcion para traer los datos de las transacciones por ende devuelve el error **404 BAD REQUEST** y el Id en la url aparece como **"undefind"** :(

Comment: No es muy claro el pantallazo porque tienes varios `console` pero no se explica cual es cual, sin embargo, por lo que entiendo, `extractedUserId` se renderea primero como `null` y ya despueés cambia a un `int` y quieres que solo ejecute la función del `useEffect` hasta que sea un `int`, es correcto?

Comment: Ah vale, Si es exactamente lo que necesito que pase, por que se estan enviando varias peticiones y retornando como BAD REQUEST antes de que cambie a INT y se pinte la informacion en la tabla, debido a esto cuando trato de acceder a ese recurso con otro usuario de una vez me desloguea por ese error! @Sr1871

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes verificar que tu `extractedUserId` sea diferente a undefined, antes de hacer la petición

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (extractedUserId !== undefined){
        getUserDetails(extractedUsername);
        getCdrsListMadeByUser(extractedUserId)
    }
 },[extractedUserId]);
```

Comment: Hombre muchas gracias por ayudarme a aclarar la mente, eso era exactamente lo que queria, parece ser que no puedo votar por "Esta respuesta es util" por ser nuevo en la comunidad, pero muchas gracias. Me funciono poniendo fuera de la condicion el getUserDetails(extractedUsername);